# How to implement Start & End View feature like in the iPhone Calendar App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

Does everyone know, how to implement a Start & End view like in the iPhone Calendar App. I know it's a Grouped Table view with Custom cells at the top. But how do I implement the `NSDatePicker` at the bottom of the View. I've tried to implement the `NSDatePicker` with the Storyboard but there's always a small gap between the `NSDatePicker` and the bottom of the view.

It should look like this:

[image: NSDatePicker implementation from the iPhone Calendar App]

**Edit:** The solution for this issue is simple. I added two container vies, one as grouped table view and one as view controller with the NSDatePicker.

Comment: how does your view look like?

Comment: Have you tried two separate views. One for the top with the grouped table view and the one at the bottom with just the date picker?

Comment: It looks like the uploaded file, but only with a small gap between the NSDatePicker and the bottom of the view.